# Calabash iOS: how to get value using query command

Tags: ios, ruby, ui-automation, calabash

I'm trying to get the value of every class using query command.
Below is the sample UI component that I get:

```
[0] {
          "class" => "UITabBarSwappableImageView",
             "id" => "imageView-34",
           "rect" => {
        "center_x" => 288,
               "y" => 522,
           "width" => 48,
               "x" => 264,
        "center_y" => 538,
          "height" => 32
    },
          "frame" => {
             "y" => 2,
         "width" => 48,
             "x" => 6,
        "height" => 32
    },
          "label" => nil,
    "description" => "<UITabBarSwappableImageVie....>"
```

On Android, I can just use this to list all the values of class components:

```
query("*", :class)
```

However, I can't seem to use the same command on iOS.
I get this as the result:

```
irb(main):135:0> query "*", :class
[
    [ 0] nil,
    [ 1] nil,
    [ 2] nil,
    [ 3] nil
]
```

I know that with the labels, I can use :accessibilityLabel to do the job, but not when I try to get value from class/id/etc.

Could someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:  'class' is not a selector on UIView instances

Long answer:

```
# query( < look for some views >, < selector on the views found > )

# look for buttons marked 'big button' and call 'isSelected' selector on them
query("button marked:'big button'", :isSelected")

# look for labels marked 'title' and call 'text' selector on them
query("label marked:'title'", :text)

# look for all views and call 'class' selector on them
# whoops!  'class' is not a selector on UIView instances
query "*", :class
```

Taking a step back, I think I know what you are trying to do - get a comprehensive list of views that are visible.

Have a look at https://github.com/jmoody/briar/blob/master/lib/briar/irbrc.rb

Example output is here:  https://gist.github.com/jmoody/8031917

Instead of calling 'class' in the query, iterate over the results returned by query and look for the value of the 'class' key.

```
query('*').map { |result| result['class'] }
```