# Is it possible to directly query and return 2 fields per object?

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

For example when querying a screen in an app, can I only return the text of an object and the center_y coordinate?

So far I've gotten just the text by using the query :

```
query("CalendarCellView", :text)
```

but can I get just the text and center_y fields returned in the results hash (without editing the hash myself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't.  There isn't support for multiple selectors at the moment, which would be necessary to select multiple parts of the output.  There aren't even selectors for some elements at all - see the answer in this post [Calabash iOS: how to get value using query command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214292/calabash-ios-how-to-get-value-using-query-command).  I don't think there is a selector for center_y.

This leaves you with a map or select as the only option.